# php - phpMailer Cron add's an email to the queue while it shouldn't

Tags: php, email, cron, queue, phpmailer

I have a script that periodically (every ~5 minutes) requests a bunch of data from an API and possibly sends a email.

However I recently got contacted by the server administrator that there a huge amount of queued mails which will never be sent because of the Cron.

However as it stands right now it should never send the emails because it should never pass the if-statements in which the mailing code is placed.

Script more or less does the same thing twice, but with some different emails:

```
/* Paging - Every ~15 minutes, during non-working-times, for all dashboards that have pagerservice enabled. */

$queryPagerservice = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `dashboard` WHERE `pagerservice`=true AND (`last_pager` < NOW() - INTERVAL ".PAGER_INTERVAL." MINUTE OR `last_pager` IS NULL)");
$timeNow = date("Gi");

while ($pagerservice = mysqli_fetch_array($queryPagerservice, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '1.'; //Does the script hit this code?
    $issues = new Issues($pagerservice['id'], 'all', $dbcon);
    $array = $issues->getIssues();
    if ((count($array['aaData']) > 0) && ($timeNow > WORK_START && $timeNow < WORK_END)) {
        mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE `dashboard` SET `last_pager`=NOW() WHERE `id`='".$pagerservice['id']."'");
        $date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
        $message = "There are ".count($array['aaData'])." problems in '".$pagerservice['text']."'.";
        echo '2.'; //Does the script hit this code?
        require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        $pagerMail = new PHPMailer;
        $pagerMail->isSMTP();
        $pagerMail->Host = MAILSERVER_ADDRESS;
        $pagerMail->Port = MAILSERVER_PORT;
        $pagerMail->setFrom('pagerservice@example.com', 'EXAMPLE Pager');
        $pagerMail->addReplyTo('noreply@example.com', 'No Reply');
        $pagerMail->addAddress(PAGE_EMAIL, 'pagerservice');
        $pagerMail->addAddress(PAGER_PHONE.'@'.PAGER_PROVIDER, 'pagerservice');
        $pagerMail->Subject = 'pagerservice';
        $pagerMail->Body = $message;
        $pagerMail->AltBody = $message;
        $pagerMail->send();
    }
}

/* Notifications - Every ~15 minutes, during working hours, for all dashboards that have notifications enabled. */

$queryNotification = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `dashboard` WHERE `notification`=true AND (`last_notification` < NOW() - INTERVAL ".NOTIF_INTERVAL." MINUTE OR `last_notification` IS NULL)");
$timeNow = date("Gi");

while ($notifications = mysqli_fetch_array($queryNotification, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '3.'; //Does the script hit this code?
    $issues = new Issues($notifications['id'], 'all', $dbcon);
    $array = $issues->getIssues();
    if ((count($array['aaData']) > 0) && ($timeNow > WORK_START && $timeNow < WORK_END)) {
        mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE `dashboard` SET `last_notification`=NOW() WHERE `id`='".$notifications['id']."'");
        $date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
        $message = "(Notif) There are ".count($array['aaData'])." problems in '".$pagerservice['text']."'.";
        echo '4.'; //Does the script hit this code?
        require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        $notifMail = new PHPMailer;
        $notifMail->isSMTP();
        $notifMail->Host = MAILSERVER_ADDRESS;
        $notifMail->Port = MAILSERVER_PORT;
        $notifMail->setFrom('notifications@example.com', 'EXMAPLE Notificator');
        $notifMail->addReplyTo('noreply@example.com', 'No Reply');
        $notifMail->addAddress(NOTIF_EMAIL, 'notifications');
        $notifMail->Subject = 'notification';
        $notifMail->Body = $message;
        $notifMail->AltBody = $message;
        $notifMail->send();
    }
}
```

[image: picture of queue]

Attempted fix: I moved the `require_once()` call to within the if-statement. This didn't fix it.

There is no other code in the script that is in any way related to sending email's. And the code that is e-mail related isn't executed (as shown by the fact that neither `1.`, `2.`, `3.` nor `1.` is echoed).

I am looking for any tips as to what can cause the cron script to queue an email that is never sent by the SMTP server.

Comment: Personally, I would ask for clarification of what this means. If an email is in the SMTP queue, it will not be affected by anything the cron is subsequently doing. If the emails are in the SMTP queue and not being sent, there is a problem with the SMTP server or the target email address.

Comment: @ChrisBint Every time the cron is executed a mail is added to the SMTP queue, even though the code that 'could' cause this, isn't even executed. I will ask for clarification soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron jobs have no user interface, so if the script outputs anything to the stderror or stdoutput it will cause the cron system to generate an email, to contain that output. This is how you would know your cron is having problems, or how you monitor things like "I did 10 things this run" type of stuff.

It looks to me as if your script has some kind of output either reporting errors or doing your `echo '1.'` debugging code or something similiar.

First I would check all the code you say it is running for anything like `echo` or `print` etc etc, anything that would normally write info to the terminal, and remove/rethink it.

Then change the cron's config to send these emails to a valid email address that you actually monitor, so you know when your script is trying to tell you something.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, currently checking whether this is the cause, which seems likely. I will attempt to disable the mailing via `> /dev/null 2>&1`. Will select as the right answer once I made sure this is the cause.

Comment: It would be better to send it to a real email address, then you will see what it is trying to tell you, at least for 15 minutes or so

Comment: The script has been running fine for days, there just were a whole lot of queued emails over the course of these days.

Comment: Then something changes or the admin didnt tell you about the other 50,000 queued emails `from here to eternity`

Comment: Accepted answer; mail queuing stopped, thanks! Btw: The script runs every 5 minutes, there were about 1300 queued mails; which means the script ran fine for `1300*5/60/24 = ~4.5 days`

Comment: No actually that means it has been doing something wrong for ~4.5 days. How long has it been an active cron? I still maintain you need to see at least one of these emails rather than just throw them away. The output could be useful to fixing whatever it is

Comment: I forgot to put that in my post, but the script always `echo json_encode()`'s a array with some basic information; like that the script succeeded. I didn't know it's relevancy though, as I didn't know crons always send output via mail.

Comment: Well thats GOOD. If you change that to only generate output when it has a problem, and you chnage the email so you receive them, then you will be told when/if something ever actually goes wrong with the script and you can go straight to working out what the probelm is. Thats the whole point of this cron functionality

Comment: In a future version of the software I will do this. But as of right now it is also possibly to force the script to run in the browser via clicking a button (AJAX request), and the AJAX request uses the basic JSON output. Thanks a lot for the information, I learned a lot more about cron today.

Comment: This might be useful to you then. You can test if you are running a PHP script in the CLI by doing `if ( php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ) {` Then the same script can do different things when run from a browser to what it does when run as a CLI/CRON